# Create data frames for each unique permutation of groups of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, permutation, python-itertools

Suppose I have the following Dataframe in Python:

```
     input_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Previous': ['1000', '1000', 'latex', 'latex'], 
    'Ignore':[None, None, ['free'], ['free']], 
    'New': ['100', '200', 'nylon', 'cloth']})
```

I would like to generate the following four dataframes:

```
    df1  = pd.DataFrame({
        'Previous': ['1000','latex'],
        'Ignore': [None, ['free']],
        'New': ['100','nylon']})
    df2  = pd.DataFrame({
        'Previous': ['1000','latex'],
        'Ignore': [None, ['free']],
        'New': ['100','cloth']})
    df3  = pd.DataFrame({
        'Previous': ['1000','latex'],
        'Ignore': [None, ['free']],
        'New': ['200','nylon']})
    df4  = pd.DataFrame({
        'Previous': ['1000','latex'],
        'Ignore': [None, ['free']],
        'New': ['200','cloth']})
```

How can I accomplish this?

Edit: I have arrived at the following solution by modifying @TheMaster 's answer:

```
out=[pd.DataFrame(j) for j in c([i[1] for i in input_df.iterrows()], len(input_df['Previous'].unique())) if len(pd.DataFrame(j)['Previous'].unique()) == len(input_df['Previous'].unique())]
```

This solution keeps only the output where the 'Previous' column has all unique entries.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations as c
out=[pd.DataFrame(j) for j in c([i[1] for i in df.iterrows()],2)]
```

```
Out[2]:
[  Previous  New
 0     1000  100
 1     1000  200,
   Previous    New
 0     1000    100
 2    latex  nylon,
   Previous    New
 0     1000    100
 3    latex  cloth,
   Previous    New
 1     1000    200
 2    latex  nylon,
   Previous    New
 1     1000    200
 3    latex  cloth,
   Previous    New
 2    latex  nylon
 3    latex  cloth]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. However, I would like to avoid the extraneous first and last entry present in your answer. Additionally, I forgot to mention that there are additional columns in the input Dataframe that I would like to keep. I have edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: @oliverjenkins Why are they "extraneous"?

Comment: They are not desired in the output. I have modified your solution slightly and solved it, see my edit to the original question. Thank you for your input!